# openNi coding & install error

Tags: kinect, openni, openkinect

I am new bie to kinect & programming with open Ni

I have below package installed in my system for kinect v2 sensor.
[image: Installed kinects]
i downloaded SDK 2.0 . I have downloaded open Ni from below link. my sysemm confguration meet kinect specification. i tried kinect evalution; all things working fine. Now i just try to write first code on open NI. i got below error.let me know how to solve the issue

windows8.1 os; 64 bit; direct11 gt630 grapghic card ;4gb RAM

[image: open ni error]

[openni download link](http://structure.io/openni)

Comment: Does openni even support the kinect 2?
Also from what i remember from the first kinect and openni was that you didn't need the official SDK to use NI/NITE.

Comment: then how can use the sensor, how to get start with kinect2 sensor

Comment: Use microsoft's drivers and SDK, they have plenty of examples, none of which require OpenNI.